# How to open a new tab within window.open window - Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, microsoft-edge

I have below code for opening a new window.

```
window.open("https://www.w3schools.com", "_blank", "location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");
```

It opens new window as expected. If there is a link button within this new window, once user clicks on it, how to open it as new tab within the same new window instead of opening another new window in MS Edge.

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Probably @serg06. If anyone have any idea.

Comment: @serg06 if you have any idea about this. how to get the window of newly open window from this window.open(url, "_blank"); so that I can do window.print() to the newly open window. Thanks!

Comment: I also believe that it is not possible. Even if you put the button inside window.open with an onclick function that also uses window.open when using specs like _blank or _parent it will close window.open and open a new tab or replace the current window

Comment: You can test this using something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/3jvqpbk8/

Comment: ok @ViniciusVasconcelos will try. But I am looking something different. Anyway thank you!

Comment: @CodeVenture I thank you for asking such an interesting question.

Comment: Use Chrome or Opera or Firefox.

Comment: If the page you're opening is to an external site this won't be possible. However, if it's to another page on your site (or a page you have control over) you could utilize URL search parameters and set a flag there. [See window.location.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with serg06, when you use the provided code to open new window, you will find that it is just a `popup`, not a `tab` window. It doesn't have page navigation tool(go forward or backward), only when you convert it to a tab can you achieve your requirement. like this:

[image]

Otherwise, if you use `target='_blank'`, you can only open a new tab in the parent page.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I would like to show as tab but it is something by default displayed as window instead of tab.